# Random Minecraft Seed not containing new biomes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I often search for nice seeds on the internets but then I think I want a unique seed for my server and not one that is already in use by many other servers.

When I generate a new map with a random seed (leaving the field blank), the server builds a map prior to the version (I think it's 1.7) which does not contain MESA biome and generally the stuff added since 1.7.

My expectation is that a map created by the newest version of the server also contains the new stuff. Now I'm running the most recent server versions but still have old maps, although I just created them.

I have two questions:

- Is it just bad luck?
- Is there a way I can integrate the missing biomes randomly into my current map without losing chunks we already built on?

I'm using the most recent **spigot** with only a little amount of plugins.
When I put in a seed found on the internet, containing the new biomes, spigot / the server does not complain and happily generates the map with the new biomes.

*Edit:*

Thanks for your answer. The suggested tool showed the *missing* biomes - I just didn't look far enough.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried getting the seed via `/seed` and using them to create the same world with vanilla minecraft singleplayer? If it's different, it's a problem with Spigot. If it's the same, you are likely just having bad luck with the seeds. Mesa Biomes and Glaciers and such are rare. On my own world, the closest Mesa was more than 3000 blocks away from spawn. You can also try [AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262200-v3-6-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder) to find specific biomes in your world.

Comment: That's some useful information. Going to try AMIDST later

Comment: I'm glad you found your biomes! I first used AMIDST because I spent 6+ rl hours looking for Ice Spikes Plains biome. 30 sec later, found 5 more within reasonable travel distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests seem perfectly valid. If the game generates the biomes properly with seeds that have those biomes, then you're simply suffering from bad luck or you aren't looking around enough to know that your desired biomes are not available. They must be there somewhere, but some of the newer biomes are frustratingly rare or commonly distant from spawn.

As was mentioned in the comments, to more easily verify the convenient placement of a given biome in a given seed is to test it in [AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262200-v3-6-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder). That way you won't have to fly around in creative mode to tell what the biome layout will be.